# lbrack, rbrack vs [ and ]

Tags: brackets

**Question:** What's the difference between `\left\lbrack1,2,3\right\rbrack` and `\left[1,2,3\right]`? Why would I use one versus the other?

*I recently started using [mathlive](https://cortexjs.io/mathlive/demo/), a WYSIWYG LaTeX editor, for a web project. I noticed that it uses `\lbrack` and `\rbrack` for square brackets. In years of using LaTeX, I've never encountered these commands before and so am curious*

**Example:**

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    \left\lbrack1,2,3\right\rbrack
\end{equation}
% vs
\begin{equation}
    \left[1,2,3\right]
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The definition can be found inside your document via the command `\show\lbrack`. This way you will get as output"

`> \lbrack=macro:`

`->[.`

No difference at all... It is possible programmatic the reason of this difference for debugging purposes of your WYSIWYG app.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

LaTeX defines these via

```
\def\lbrack{[}
\def\rbrack{]}
```

so there is no difference in behaviour. However the command forms can be used on keyboard layouts that make `[]` inconvenient. They can also bee used inside latex optional arguments, or after a command that would otherwise parse `[` as an optional argument such as `\\` as an alternative to hiding `[]` in `{}`.

Comment: +1. I'd add the case "or after a command that would otherwise parse `[` as an optional argument", such as \\. (This does not apply to OP's specific example, but is worth mentioning since both the question title and your answer are broad and general)

Comment: @marquinho will add, thanks